# Raster calculator: IF (A-B=A) THEN reclassify

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Without using any Python (i.e. only thru QGIS interface and its raster calculators), is there a way to perform and evaluation of a subtraction to be equal to one of the input rasters and, if true, reclassify those cells as an integer?

For example:

```
IF (raster_A@1 - raster_B@1 = raster_A@1, 99, NoData)
```

Into words: given a raster, I would like to check the presence of the cells of one raster over another (I guess thru their difference), and if the raster is present (raster_A@1) and the other one isn't (raster_B@1), reclassify the former raster to a unique value for all cells, otherwise NoData. I have tried doing the following using the core raster calculator:

```
(raster_A@1 - raster_B@1 = raster_A@1)*99
```

or

```
((raster_A@1 - raster_B@1) = raster_A@1)*99
```

and obviously two logics in the same instruction

```
((raster_A@1 - raster_B@1) = raster_A@1)*99 + ((raster_B@1 - raster_A@1) = raster_B@1)*-99
```

But my logic is faulty: it returns a raster which histogram shows only 0 to 0

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Comment: This is an identity operation. The only value where this is True is when rasterB is zero. The value will be `0 x 99` when False, so only zeros means that rasterB is never zero.

Comment: @Vince - that's fair enough. Any tips on how to evaluate true for all the raster_A@1 cells after the subtraction operation? Or it cannot be done in the QGIS interface (i.e. only thru a script)?